# in wordpress how to show a custom post as a category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to show a CPT as a category. To be more precise here is my example,

I have created a CPT called vendor and it is having own taxonomy.

Eg: Vendor1 with books as category

In woocommerce product category I am displaying the same books as category, in addition to that I want to have the vendor1 (from CPT) as its sub cateogry so that I can add products and display then under vendor1 in front end.

I hope I am not confusing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have an instance of a Custom Post Type used as a category.

However, you can hook into the add/update/delete of your custom post type... and create/edit/remove a category that Woo will look at. It will be a little tricky covering your add/edit/delete screnarios..but once you have it done....it should fit your requirement.